# Как одним запросом получить среднее и максимальные значения по группам и всей таблице?

Tags: sql, oracle

Есть стандартная [схема HR](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/COMSC/diagrams.htm#COMSC00016) с таблицей [employees](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/k8zkivxrwp3xddekpqldtecc8), помогите составить в ней запрос:

> вычислите одним запросом среднюю и максимальную заработные платы по отделам и всей организации.

Вот так делаю двумя запросами:

```
SELECT department_id,ROUND(AVG (salary)) avg_salary, MAX (salary) max_salary_on_departments
FROM employees GROUP BY department_id;

SELECT ROUND(AVG (salary)) avg_salary, MAX (salary) max_salary_on_departments
FROM employees;
```

А как получить тотже результат одним запросом?

Comment: Дарья, нет «стандартных» схем. Добавьте в вопрос структуру таблиц и ваши попытки решить задачу и вам помогут

Comment: @nörbörnën Добавила пример

Comment: добавьте во второй запрос null в качестве department_id и склейте оба запроса union all

Comment: @nörbörnën А можно пример? :3

Comment: @nörbörnën Она про эти схемы https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/COMSC/installation.htm#COMSC001

Comment: @Дарья, воспользуйтесь [window functions](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/mysql-8.0-en/window-functions-usage.html) - обратите внимание на третий пример

Comment: @Alpensin спасибо за комментарий! я не знал, что в оракл есть что-то подобное

Comment: @nörbörnën А вопросу плюсик добавить. Его какой-то дядька поправил и теперь он - узкий, с данными, попыткой решения. Вообщем, почти  идеальный вопрос.

Comment: @0xdb шикарно, первая ссылка стала адекватна теме вопроса

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дарья, вы правильно составили запросы! Используйте оператор [UNION](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries004.htm) для того чтобы объединить результаты:

```
SELECT
  department_id,
  ROUND(AVG(salary)) avg_salary,
  MAX(salary) max_salary_on_departments 
FROM
  employees
where
  DEPARTMENT_ID is not null
GROUP BY
  department_id

UNION 

SELECT
  null as department_id,
  ROUND(AVG(salary)) avg_salary,
  MAX(salary) max_salary_on_departments 
FROM
  employees
```

Comment: Большое спасибо :)

Comment: @0xdb, спасибо, что оставил мне доступ к своему oracle :)

Comment: Всмысле, я не поняла какой доступ? :(

Comment: @Дарья не обращайте внимания, предыдущий комментарий адресован [0xdb](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/217579/0xdb), другому участнику community

Comment: @nörbörnën Пожалуйста, пользуйся на здоровье. Странно, не было никакого уведомления на комментарий, хотя @ и ник правильный

Comment: @0xdb прошу, накати в бд `SH`-схему )

Comment: @nörbörnën Накатил все. Пробуй, пароли=схема, например hr/hr.

Answer (score 3):

Самое простое, вот так (на [db<>fiddle](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/k8zde4glnlkczoy4h97jz69uw)):

```
select
    case grouping (department_id) 
    when 0 then coalesce (to_char (department_id), 'outsource') 
    else 'total' end department,  
    round (avg(salary)) avgsalary, 
    max(salary) maxsalary 
from hr.employees
group by rollup (department_id)
order by department_id
/
DEPARTMENT        AVGSALARY  MAXSALARY
---------------- ---------- ----------
10                     4400       4400
20                     9500      13000
30                     4150      11000
40                     6500       6500
50                     3476       8200
60                     5760       9000
70                    10000      10000
80                     8956      14000
90                    19333      24000
100                    8601      12008
110                   10154      12008
outsource              7000       7000
total                  6462      24000
```

Из вопроса непонятно, что делать с внештатными сотрудниками, оставил их в `outsource`.